# Highcharts display full number or any format instead of k

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am using highcharts

In case of having numbers in thousands 1000 and greater the chart for example gauge chart the speedometer will display 1k 2k .. not 1000 2000

I think its designed in that way for not displaying full numbers so that it is kept readable

How can i display the full number or any other label instead of k

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `format` parameter so Highcharts won't do its own formatting.

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: '{value}'
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to send my values. I only want to display another character instead of the k letter that is displayed instead of thousand (000)

Comment: i tried adding array of values for format its added for every tick .. i want labels given to be added tick by tick

Answer (score 2):

Simply change [`numericSymbols`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#lang.numericSymbols).

Snippet:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        numericSymbols: [ "A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F"]
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7ndqujhq/

Comment: This snippets remove numeric values 
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        numericSymbols: [ "A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F"]
    }
});